# Set environment variable for fastAPI on Cloud RUN

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to set environment variables using docker (for fastAPI) but clod run doesn't want to see them. I tried many solutions, what would be a good way? I mention that I use the docker image in cloud run

Comment: What do you mean by `Cloud RUN`?

Comment: The API  it's deployed on an Google Cloud Run instance

Comment: Cloud Run does not use Docker. Environment variables are set by the deployment command. Update your question to show how you are building and deploying the container.

Comment: Where do you set your environment variable? In your dockerfile? In the Cloud Run deployment configuration? How do you read them in your app?